# How does inotify work?

Tags: inotify

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify),

> inotify is a Linux kernel subsystem which notices changes to the file system. It replaced the previous dnotify.

Programs that sync files (such as crashplan, dropbox, git) recomend in user guides that the user increase `max_user_watches` ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148171/dropbox-error-echo-100000-sudo-tee-proc-sys-fs-inotify-max-user-watches), [2](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/client/troubleshooting/real-time), [3](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers)).

From what I understand about inotify, the OS is "told" that a file has been changed, instead of requiring the OS to "go looking" for changes.

I assume that there is an "inotify" file created in every directory. Is this correct? Is there a way to interact with inotify from the command line?

**Resources**
[Why are inotify events different on an NFS mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81663/why-are-inotify-events-different-on-an-nfs-mount)
[Inotifywait for large number of files in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77141/inotifywait-for-large-number-of-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: You probably won't find the answers to your questions this way (at least, not easily) but you should run `grep --exclude=arch -r inotify` in the Linux kernel sources.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Inotify is an internal kernel facility. There is no “inotify file”. There are dedicated system calls [`inotify_init`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_init), [`inotify_add_watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_add_watch) and [`inotify_rm_watch`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_rm_watch) that allow processes to register themselves to be notified when certain filesystem events happen. When the event happens, the process receives a description of the event through the file descriptor returned by `inotify_init`.

The OS isn't “told” that a file has been changed: it knows, because it's doing the changing. It's the application that's told that a file has been changed instead of having to go looking.

The program [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) provides a simple way to use inotify from the command line.

Comment: The `inotify` interface MAY be offered by filesystems. Not all do. Pseudo (generated programmatically) filesystems like /tmp, /proc,. ... don't.